# How to move system clock time forward/backward?

Tags: command-line, time, clock

I know commands for setting specific time and/or date, but can't find ones which move the time relative to the current time.

What are the commands to move the time forward/backward x seconds/minutes/hours? (And possibly also days/months/years?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command to set the system time is [`date`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date). You need to be root to set the system time. `date` sets the time to the given time, not to a relative amount from the current time, because that latter behavior would be pretty pointless. You can build a command that modifies the current time by a relative amount by making a calculation on the output of `date` and feeding it back to `date`, e.g. (on non-embedded Linux)

```
date $(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S -d '1 hour ago')
```

Beware that if you're running a timekeeping system such as NTP, changing the clock like this will confuse it. Stop it first.

Running `date` sets the system time, not the hardware clock. Under Linux, run [`hwclock --systohc`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock) to copy the system time to the hardware clock; this is done automatically on a clean shutdown.

If you wanted to see the time in a different timezone, forget all this and set the desired timezone instead. Under Linux, run [`tzselect`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tzselect) to set the system timezone. To run a program in a different timezone, set the `TZ` environment variable, e.g.

```
export TZ=Asia/Tokyo
emacs
```

If you want to run a program and make it believe that the time is different from what it really is, run it under the program [`faketime`](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime).

```
faketime '1 hour ago' date
```

Comment: Or `date -Ins -s $(date -Ins -d '-1 hour')`

Comment: @Zaz you could post your comment as a new answer

Comment: @SaulloCastro: Done.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the following format to get the amount of time ahead of the current time:

```
$ date --date='1 month'
Sun Sep 17 15:01:11 CST 2017
$ date --date='1 month'
Sun Sep 17 15:01:15 CST 2017
$ date --date='1 month 2 hours'
Sun Sep 17 17:01:23 CST 2017
$ date --date='1 month 2 hours 3 minutes'
Sun Sep 17 17:04:30 CST 2017
```

Also you can use `ago` for a time before the current date:

```
$ date
Fri Aug 18 16:14:41 CST 2017
$ date --date='1 month 2 days ago'
Sat Sep 16 16:14:43 CST 2017
```

You can use the `--set` option for **setting** time but adding a `+` sign before the number of hours, minutes, etc, that you want to add to the actual date:

```
$ date
Thu Aug 17 15:07:00 CST 2017
$ date --set='+1 day +1 hour'
Fri Aug 18 16:07:24 CST 2017
$ date
Fri Aug 18 16:07:31 CST 2017
$ date --set='+1 month 3 days +1 hour'
Thu Sep 21 17:07:42 CST 2017
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: `sudo date --set='+1 hour'`. Thank you very much! This seems to be the most concise way to do it!

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

```
date -Ins -s $(date -Ins -d '-1 hour')
```

Comment: When going from a comment to an answer, it is preferred to add some prose explaining how this works, and maybe why this answer is better/different from the others.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right,  in UNIX SVR4,  there was a  "-a"  option to the "date" command, which would allow the superuser to adjust the clock forward or backward some number of seconds.